# ASP.NET core razor page value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to ASP.NET core and razor page.
I hav ecreated a button and assigned a page handler to delete the entry.
When I'm trying to delete im getting a null reference error.
When I run the code and click the button to delete an entry,
im getting a null exception error

I want to know where I'm making mistake and some guidance to improve my coding.
Thank you in advance for those who helped.

This is my index page

```
@page
@model BookList.Pages.BookPages.IndexModel

       
            <form method="post">
                @if (Model.Books.Count()>0)
                {
                    <table class="table table-dark border">
                        <tr class="table-secondary">
                         @foreach (var book in Model.Books)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => book.Name)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => book.Author)
                                </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@book.Id" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" asp-route-id="@book.Id" asp-page="Edit">Edit</a>
                                   
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>No books available</p>
                }
            </form>
```

This is my page model

```
        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            Books = await _dbContext.Books.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> onPostDelete(int id)
        {
            var book = await _dbContext.Books.FindAsync(id);

            if (book == null)
                return NotFound();

            _dbContext.Books.Remove(book);

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: StackTrace of the NullReferenceException would be helpful.

Comment: Looks like after a delete there are no more books available. Please provide error text.

Comment: Ive added the StackTrace.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to send a model in your page like

```
var allBooks=  await _dbContext.Books.ToList();

return View(allBooks);
```

if this does not work, share your whole error page it may contain serious explanation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, `Model.Books` is null.
You will get null exception when you try to `.Count()` a null collection.

You can replace at your razor view

```
@if (Model.Books.Count()>0)
```

with

```
@if (Model.Books?.Count()>0)
```

to handle the null via [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Otherwise, handle the null at the controller from

```
Books = await _dbContext.Books.ToListAsync();
```

to

```
Books = (await _dbContext.Books.ToListAsync()) ?? new List<Book>();
```

via [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

**Edit from my earlier discussion with OP**:

Changed the capitalization in controller action from

```
public async Task<IActionResult> onPostDelete(int id)
```

to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int id)
```

Comment: I tried this first, it solves the null exception but it does not delete the book entry in db. and also shows no books availabe even i have entries in my db

Comment: Are you familiar with the debugger? Put a breakpoint on the "}" closing bracket of your OnGet() controller action. Then hover your mouse over your "Books" collection to see if your Books return null.

Comment: I will recommend first doing a brief read through on how to pause at breakpoints, read variables at various blocks of your code. This can help in self understanding on what goes wrong and at where: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: When i go to this page i could get the books details. Its getting displayed. The null reference occur when i press the delete button. also when i press the button its not going to the page handler.. i checked this  by adding a breakpoint on OnpostDelete .

Comment: Thanks! It worked when i changed from onPostDelete to OnPostDelete